# Cycle through radio button input questions one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a multiple choice quiz. Basically, I want each question div to display one at a time on the screen. When the user clicks on a choice, it then moves on to the next question div.

```
<div class="question_section" id="q1">
    <div class="question">
        <p>Are you tall?</p>
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="yes">Yes.</input><br/>
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="no">No.</input><br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

(A question section *ideally* should be able to contain more than one question. As in, I would like to be able to occasionally display 2 questions at once and only move onto the next screen if both are answered. But I don't know if this is possible.)

The questions and question sections will be different for each quiz, so I'd like to write jquery code that does it without me having to specify each question id.

I have the current fiddle that isn't quite working correctly... could someone advise me on how to do this?

http://jsfiddle.net/d6nZP/155/

Comment: I think you just have a simple syntax error: the function to your click call is missing curly braces. http://jsfiddle.net/57m4dacc/

PS. that firebug plugin didn't detect the syntax error, but the chrome debug console did.

Comment: Oh geez, you're right. Feeling a bit silly now, but at least it's all worked out. Thank you for pointing this out!!